# scons build in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scons

I have converted a static library project and an exe project to Scons project in ECLIPSE. These were building fine by Makefile.
But when I am building the static library project it gives an error as below -

```
=== Running SCons at 18/11/13 8:55 PM ====
Command line: /usr/bin/scons -u --jobs=8
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: Debug
o Debug/add.o -c add.cpp
sh: o: not found
ar rc Debug/libadd.a Debug/add.o
ar: Debug/add.o: No such file or directory
scons: *** [Debug/libadd.a] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Duration 301 ms.
```

1) my main objective is to a trigger a build once somehow (in the exe project) and both the project will be compiled in ECLIPSE. Is there a way to see and edit a SConscript in eclipse.

2) How do I do it? By manually writing SConscript and SConstruct file? :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the SCons output like SCons can't find the compiler on your system.  What OS are you using?  And what version of SCons?  (Type `scons --version` to see that.)